# How to disable Automatic Calculation in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query with 4 calculated fields , one of them calculate the running sum using DSum

When running this query and go to the last record it is taking some time (that is normal and OK)

But the problem is that MS Access recalculate this field every time I scroll up or down using mouse wheel, and this recalculation taking a very long time that make this query unusable

I think MS Access do this recalculation because it is multi user application so I change it to Exclusive (File > Options > Client Settings > Advanced > Default open mode > Exclusive) , but this not help

So Im looking for something like Excel to disable automatic calculation and calculate what you need and when you need using VBA for MS Access or at least prevent MS Access from recalculate the query every time I scroll up or down.

- no more than one user will use my database at the same time
- the query has about 40,000 records

Comment: I doubt you can turn off 'recalculation' in this way. Why don't you drop the query into a report and view the report. Then the data is static on the page and no recalculation is required.

Comment: thanks Nick.McDermaid , I will use a report to view the query if I don't find any way to disable recalculate, but now I'm using subform to view the query results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nick wrote, you can't.

To view the data without recalculation, put it into a report, or use a `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT INTO` action query to save it to a temporary table. The latter is especially useful, if you want to do further calculations on the data, or if it is the recordsource of another query.

Comment: Thanks @Andre451 , I will try SELECT INTO and see , I tested the report now , it is really slow! 3 to 4 minutes to open 8000 records so I will not use it

Comment: creating temporary table is slow too , It seems that there is no way to disable calculation in MS Access like Excel , so I will delete the calculated field with DSum function until I find a solution or workaround, thank you all for help

Comment: @Fadi: Filling the temporary table should take about as long as moving to the last record in the original query. The field has to be calculated for each row once. -- You should post your query in a new question. Perhaps it can be modified to an Aggregation query instead of using DSum.

Comment: Thanks again @Andre451, nearly I do what I want depending on your suggesting but instead of creating temporary table I used an array and instead of using DSum I used VBA function to calculate the running sum and fill the array mCal(mID) only one time then the calculated field take its value from this array , (mID is the PK of my table , Long) , I will test this more but until now it seems very fast and give me correct results